# Verified TLS connection established to azdcs-gov.mail.protection.outlook.com

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, postfix-mta

When I send mail using postfix via TLS, sometime it shows invalid cert: Certificate is expired with server azdcs-gov.mail.protection.outlook.com.
I took tcpdump. And it shows certificates are valid and not expired.

postfix version:2.8.2

openssl version: 1.0.1u

I also verified postfix and openssl bug list on their sites, but not able to find any such bug reported.

Can any one help me here what could be going wrong here?